# How to plot the following figure via matlab hist function?

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, matlab-figure

How to plot the following figure via matlab hist function?

Group 1: [10, 10, 20]; and Group 2: [15, 10, 8]. Each group consists of three algorithms' running times.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab: Plotting bar groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672384/matlab-plotting-bar-groups)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HIST` is not a solution to your problem. Please try to look for the [`bar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) function

A sample snippet may look like

```
g1 = [10,10,20];
g2 = [15,10,8];
algStr = sprintfc('Algorithm %d',1:3);
bar(categorical({'Group1','Group2'}),[g1;g2])
legend(algStr)
```

You will also need to learn how to tweak the axes of the figure to match exactly to your sample graph. But I think I will leave it for you to find out.

Answer (score 2):

It's not something you can do with the hist function, but something you can do with the [bar](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) function:

```
 bar([10, 10, 20; 15, 10, 8])
```